# GHDL no crea la unidad del test bench al utilizar la bandera -e

Tags: vhdl

Tengo una simple compuerta lógica y su respectivo ***test bench*** descritos en ***VHDL***

`g_AND.vhdl`

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity g_AND is
port (
    A: in std_logic;
    B: in std_logic;
    R: out std_logic
);
end entity g_AND;

architecture rtl of g_AND is begin

    R <= A and B;

end architecture rtl;
```

`test_bench.vhdl`

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_bench is
end entity test_bench;

architecture rtl of test_bench is

    -- union de componente a probar
    component g_AND
    port (
        A:  in std_logic;
        B:  in std_logic;
        R:  out std_logic
    );
    end component g_AND;

    -- declaracion de seniales
    signal sig_a: std_logic := '0';
    signal sig_b: std_logic := '0';
    signal sig_r: std_logic;

begin

    dut: g_AND port map (
        A => sig_a,
        B => sig_b,
        R => sig_r
    );

    process begin
        sig_a <= '0';
        sig_b <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;

        sig_a <= '0';
        sig_b <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;

        sig_a <= '1';
        sig_b <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;

        sig_a <= '1';
        sig_b <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
    end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

Al analizar las dos entidades respectivas no hay problema alguno, pero al querer crear la unidad con el comando `ghdl -e test_bench` no se crea mi unidad, pero tampoco hay códigos de error, por lo tanto no puedo seguir con con los comandos respectivos para crear mi archivo de señales y abrirlo en gtkwave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es que se puede obtener el mismo resultado si después de la elaboración `ghdl -e test_bench` utilizamos la opción de correr `-r` con ghdl, y sus respectivas opciones para crear el archivo `vcd`. Finalizando con este proceso:

```sh
$ ghdl -a g_AND.vhdl test_bench.vhdl
$ ghdl -e test_bench
$ ghdl -r test_bench --stop-time=100ns --vcd=waves.vcd
```